# Javascript, Jquery - break if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part of code:

```
if(mess <= 0 || mess < -width) {
img_container.find('ul').animate({'margin-left' : mess + 'px' }, 1000);
}
```

I need this to stop working when **mess** is lesser the **-width**. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe `if(mess <= 0 || mess < (width*-1) ) `

Comment: What do you mean stop working? You do not want it to go into the if? Or do you want the animation to stop at some point?

Comment: @epascarello That is the intention. mess is always 0 or less, and when mess reach value which is lesser then width function needs to stop working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if you are getting width as string, if yes, use JS `parseInt` function.

If you are looking to stop animation syntax, see on http://api.jquery.com/stop/

It could be `img_container.find('ul').stop();`

This could help:

```
if(mess < (-1 * width)){
   img_container.find('ul').stop();
}
```

Comment: Um, how is that any different to `-width`?

Comment: @raina77ow width is a number - width of all children elements.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want it to do into the if the mess is less than the width?

You want to use AND instead of OR

```
if(mess <= 0 && mess > -width) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the condition to fail if `mess` is less than `-width`, which means you only want it to *succeed* if `mess >= -width`.

Since it's a required condition just like `mess <= 0`, you need `&&` instead of `||`.